# Funciones "genericas" en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Necesito hacer que una función para verificar si ya esta abierto un winForm, la cual es de la siguiente manera:

```
private FrmNewElement newElement=null;

private FrmNewElement FormInstance
{
    get
       {
         if(newElement==null)
         {
           newElement = new FrmNewElement(new elementModel());
         }
       }
}

private void btnNewElement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            FremNeElement newElement = this.FormInstance;
            newElement.Show();
            newElement.BringToFront();
}
```

FrmNewElement es una pantalla de Winform, lo que necesito es que esta función "reciba" un winForm para verificar si ya está abierto, independientemente del tipo de variable, o sea, que reciba un FrmNewElement, un FrmStockList, FrmAuthorizartionReport o cualquier elemento que sea un winForm

Comment: Investiga el patrón Singleton

Answer (score 0):

Si queres hacer un método que reciba cualquier formulario, debes fijarte que tienen en común esos objetos, en este caso todos heredan de la clase `Form`, entonces tenes que hacer un metodo que reciba como parametros un `Form`.

```
public bool VerificarAbierto(Form formulario)
{
   //tu logica
}
```